# Lower-end Manual Espresso

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

Has anyone used one of the < $500 manual espresso machines like a ROK or Flair? I've read the specs (up to 10 bars for ROK, around 15 Flair) and seen some positive reviews but I'm curious about the quality of the cup.

And, ultimately, wondering if it's worth it or THAT much better than the strong coffee I get from my Aeropress.

Comment: Don't buy a coffee machine, the real coffee is made with a filter.

Filter coffee is the best and should be drank black!

Answer (score 1):

If your budget is $500 and below then you can afford a real semi-professional espresso machine, including Gaggia or Lelit, for example.

Comment: How do you see the prices of the Lelit machines or where do you buy them?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently bought a Flair Signature Pro. I have been drinking coffee for a long time, but at home I always prepared it using a moka pot, so I can't tell how it compares to other espresso makers, or to an aeropress, in terms of home making.

Nevertheless, I am really happy with it. After some initial tuning of my coffee grinder, I have been able to produce a nice cup of espresso, with its characteristic crema, texture and strength. I consider it to produce a nice cup, comparable to those I can drink in many random cafes (I live in New York City, and lived before for twenty something years in Spain, where espresso is a common drink).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pump machines for 7 or 8 years now (Quickmill Orione, then Quickmill Carola) and recently (3 months ago) switched to a Flair Pro 2.

I can't answer your question about Aeropress as I don't know Aeropress coffee. But I can compare it to pump machine espresso.

IMHO the Flair Pro 2 outperforms the Carola (which is a great pump machine), but what it makes so special is (like with any direct lever machine) you are in full control of pressure. Given standard methods (15 mins of pre-infusion, 45-55 secs total extraction time, slow rampup to 7-8 bars and slow ramp-down) I get a very sweet, thick, delicious espresso that is usually more on the "ristretto side".